# How to select group based checkbox antd in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, checkbox, antd

I want to select a group based checkbox. The problem is that when I click on the group, the entire checkbox is selected. I don't want to select the entire checkbox. this is my Initial State.

```
const plainOptions = ["can_view", "can_create", "can_update"];
state = {
  checkedList: [],
  indeterminate: true,
  checkAll: false
};
```

Method: `onchange` method basically works each individual checkbox.

```
onChange = checkedList => {
  console.log(checkedList);
  this.setState({
    checkedList,
    indeterminate:
      !!checkedList.length && checkedList.length < plainOptions.length,
    checkAll: checkedList.length === plainOptions.length
  });
};
```

This method works for selected all checkbox

```
onCheckAllChange = e => {
  console.log(e.target.checked);
  this.setState({
    checkedList: e.target.checked ? plainOptions : [],
    indeterminate: false,
    checkAll: e.target.checked
  });
};
{
  ["group", "topGroup"].map(item => (
    <div className="site-checkbox-all-wrapper">
      <Checkbox
        indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
        onChange={this.onCheckAllChange}
        checked={this.state.checkAll}
      >
        {item}
      </Checkbox>
      <CheckboxGroup
        options={plainOptions}
        value={this.state.checkedList}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

However, my accepted Data format is

```
{group:["can_view","can_create"],topGroup:["can_view","can_create"}
```

I want to get this format output when user selected on the checkbox

Here is the code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sea-1ygqu

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60612506/11872246

Comment: did you check my code is here  https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sea-1ygqu

Comment: *"I want to select a group based checkbox. The problem is that when I click on the group, the entire checkbox is selected. I don't want to select the entire checkbox."* I'm not quite sure I understand. Do you want to select half a checkbox?

Comment: I want to select role based checkbox . For example , you click on the the group - it will select first row of group and if you click on topgroup , it will select topgroup based row .

Comment: currently , when I select on group , it will select including with topgroup . I don't want to select topgroup , when I selected on group .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason both groups change when you click something in one of them is because both groups use the same internal state.

```
["group", "topGroup"].map(item => (
  <div className="site-checkbox-all-wrapper">
    <Checkbox
      indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
      onChange={this.onCheckAllChange}
      checked={this.state.checkAll}
    >
      {item}
    </Checkbox>
    <CheckboxGroup
      options={plainOptions}
      value={this.state.checkedList}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
  </div>
));
```

Both the `group` and `topGroup` use the same `this.state.checkList` state.

---

The easiest way to solve this is by extracting each group into its own component. This way they have their own state separate of each other.

[image: Edit stackoverflow-a-60764570-3982562-v1]

---

You could also opt to keep one component, but you must manage multiple internal states. You could for example use `state = { checkList: [[], []] }` where the first sub-array is to store the `group` state and the second sub-array is to store the `topGroup` state.

If groups are dynamic you can simply `map` over the groups and create your states that way:

```
state = { checkList: groups.map(() => []) };
```

You would also need to manage multiple `indeterminate` and `checkAll` states. This can be avoided when you deduce those from the `checkList` state. For example:

```
isIndeterminate(index) {
  const checkList = this.state.checkList[index];
  return checkList.length > 0 && checkList.length < plainOptions.length;
}
```

This would also avoid conflicting state, since there is one source of truth.

Comment: how can i get my accepted output . you look {group:["can_view","can_create"],topGroup:["can_view","can_create"}

Comment: I want to add new Objects when user click on checkbox. For example , When user click on group , it will store data {permission:{group:["1","2"]}}. If I click on topgroup , it will store new objects with previous one

Comment: can you look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772481/how-to-add-multiple-objects-in-reactjs