# Add or remove data based on checkbox state in react 15

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, react-state

I have a empty array in my state where I wish to push the checked data from a list. I am using material-ui for react 15 (please dont ask me to update to react 16 as that is not an option for my project).

I want to push the data in the array everytime I check on it, and pop the data everytime that checkbox item is unchecked.

Can someone put me through the logical part of how am I going to implement it.

This is what I have been doing so far.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  checkedCompaniesList: [],
};
```

}

```
<Checkbox onCheck={() => this.handleCheckedCompanies(company.name)}>

  handleCheckedCompanies = (value) => {
const companies = [...this.state.checkedCompaniesList];
console.log('>>>>>Before push>>>>>', companies);

companies.push(value);

console.log('<<<<<After push<<<<<<<', companies);

this.setState({
  checkedCompaniesList: companies,
});

console.log('<<<<<<<state array<<<<<', this.state.checkedCompaniesList);
```

}

The problem is that i get the values in the companies array, but the setState does not seem to work as intended.

Also, unchecking the checkbox again pushes the same element in the companies array.

I want to push the data in the companies array and set state to checkedCompaniesList, and remove the data whenever user unchecks it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773178/11872246

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. I just want to add that checkbox label value to an array on check, and remove it on uncheck.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code? Or an online demo? Nothing can be done if there is no actual code

Comment: Added the code snippets.

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) thanks