# How to select multiple checkbox reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using react antd. this code is worked perfectly , but I want to replace `<CheckboxGroup/>` .  Now , I am just pass plainOptions array inside `<CheckboxGroup/>` without looping, but right now I want to do loop  single `<Checkbox>` by using plainOptions array.

```
    For example : plainOptions.map(item=><Checkbox  value={item} onChange  
    {this.onChange}/>) ) // My code would be  like this

    const plainOptions = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];
    const defaultCheckedList = ['Apple', 'Orange'];

    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        checkedList: defaultCheckedList,
        indeterminate: true,
        checkAll: false,
      };

      onChange = checkedList => {
        this.setState({
          checkedList,
          indeterminate: !!checkedList.length && checkedList.length < plainOptions.length,
          checkAll: checkedList.length === plainOptions.length,
        });
      };

      onCheckAllChange = e => {
        this.setState({
          checkedList: e.target.checked ? plainOptions : [],
          indeterminate: false,
          checkAll: e.target.checked,
        });
      };
  <div className="site-checkbox-all-wrapper">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
            onChange={this.onCheckAllChange}
            checked={this.state.checkAll}
          >
            Check all
          </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <br />

        <CheckboxGroup
          options={plainOptions}
          value={this.state.checkedList}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
```

I want to use *`<Checkbox/>`* instead of CheckboxGroup. My code would be  like this

```
      For example : plainOptions.map(item=><Checkbox  value={item} onChange 
      {this.onChange}/>)
```

How it can be done ?

Here is my codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/4k6qi?file=/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for multiple states, keep one single source (`checkedList`) would be fine.

```
onCheckItem = value => e => {
  const { checkedList } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    checkedList: checkedList.includes(value)
      ? checkedList.filter(x => x !== value)
      : [...checkedList, value]
  });
};
```

```
render() {
  const { checkedList } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="site-checkbox-all-wrapper">
        <Checkbox
          indeterminate={
            checkedList.length < plainOptions.length && checkedList.length > 0
          }
          onChange={this.onCheckAllChange}
          checked={checkedList.length === plainOptions.length}
        >
          Check all
        </Checkbox>
      </div>
      <br />
      {plainOptions.map((item, idx) => (
        <Checkbox
          key={item + idx}
          onChange={this.onCheckItem(item)}
          checked={checkedList.includes(item)}
        >
          {item}
        </Checkbox>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Check all - Ant Design Demo]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391308/how-to-use-antd-multiple-checkbox-in-reactjs @keikai can you see this ?