# Cant check one checkbox, All checkbox checked after i check just one checkbox in table

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a table of data, and it has checkbox field which allows people to check it.
If i click that checkbox, it will send to database to make status of that checklist is true, i have made it and do the change status to be true in database.

this is the JSON data if i check the checkbox,
from this

```
data={"Id":"123", "checklist": false}
```

to this

```
data={"Id":"123", "checklist": true}
```

When I do checked one checkbox, this is happen:
My database is okay , it just one checkbox is checked
**The problem is when i click one of checkbox, all the checkbox are checked too at the frontend**

I have made isChecked state like this,
This is my code snippet:

```
class Apps extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isChecked: false
      }
    }

    _onSubmitChecklistClicked = async (checked,id) => {
      await RequestHandler(`${ENVIRONMENT.API_URL}api/v1.0/checklist`, {}, {id})
      this.setState({isChecked:checked})
    }


    render () {
        const {datas} = this.prop;
        const {isChecked} = this.state;
        return (........
          <tbody>
            {
              datas.map((data, i) => {
                return (
                  <tr className="t-row__low">
                    {
                      columns.map((column, j) => {
                        if (column.value === 'checklist') {
                          if(data['checklist'] != null)
                          { 
                          return <td key={j} className="row-table-contain-default" style={{whiteSpace: 'wrap' }}>{
                          <Input type="checkbox" className="input-checked" checked={isChecked} 
                          onChange={(e) => this._onSubmitChecklistClicked(e.target.checked,data.id)}></Input>}</td>
                          }
                          return <td key={j} className="row-table-contain-default"></td>
                        }
                      })
                    }
                );
              })
            }
          </tbody>
```

i dont know what to do on my attribute checked={isChecked}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple checkbox reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094108/how-to-select-multiple-checkbox-reactjs)

Comment: `checked={isChecked} ` You are basically checking checked property for all checkbox with one variable `isChecked`. Hence whatever the state, it is reflected in all the checkboxes. You need to maintain state for all the checkboxes.

Comment: @keikai i will try it, thank you

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal yes, you're right. I dont know what to do on my checked attribute, if i fill it with data['checklist'] it can't changed the checkbox, it will change when i reload the page

Comment: @HanifAlfiHammami, yes you are right. You need to store the checked state on your server and when component loads, fetch data from server and then render.