# trying to select one check box selecting all check boxes

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to presist the checkbox using local storage...after applying that...
if i select the one checkbox selecting all checkboxes...i using map function for the checkboxes...can any one help on this.....i want to select individual check box

this is the linkmof code sand box :
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-wind-rmz1z?file=/src/App.js

branches.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

// const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);
class BranchComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {},
      count: 0,
      checked: localStorage.getItem("checkbox") === "true" ? true : false
    };
  }
  CheckedBox = e => {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    let count = this.state.count;
    if (checked) {
      console.log(checked);
      this.setState({ checked: true });
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
      console.log(checked);
      this.setState({ checked: false });
    }
    this.setState({ count });
    console.log(count);

    let values = this.state.value;
    values[e.target.value] = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ value: values });

    localStorage.setItem("checkbox", e.target.checked.toString());
  };

  checkBoxSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.value);
  };
  render() {
    const arr = ["Branch 1", "Branch 2", "Branch 3"];
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.checkBoxSubmit}>
          <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
            <List className="courses-college-regis">
              {arr.map((a, key) => (
                <ListItem button key={key}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    label={a}
                    value={a}
                    type="checkbox"
                    name={a}
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                    control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                    onClick={this.CheckedBox}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </FormGroup>
          Count :{this.state.count}
          <br />
          <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default BranchComponent;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple checkbox reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094108/how-to-select-multiple-checkbox-reactjs)

Comment: no. i want to select individual check boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i updated your code is working fine,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
var localStorageData = localStorage.getItem("checkbox");
// const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);
class BranchComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {},
      count:
        localStorageData && typeof JSON.parse(localStorageData) === "object"
          ? JSON.parse(localStorageData).length
          : 0,
      checked:
        localStorageData && typeof JSON.parse(localStorageData) === "object"
          ? JSON.parse(localStorageData)
          : []
    };
  }
  CheckedBox = (e, index) => {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    let count = this.state.count;
    var addData = [...this.state.checked, index];
    if (checked) {
      console.log(checked);
      this.setState({ checked: [...new Set(addData)] });
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
      console.log(checked);
      addData = addData.filter(find => find !== index);
      this.setState({ checked: addData });
    }
    this.setState({ count: addData.length });
    console.log(count);

    let values = this.state.value;
    values[e.target.value] = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ value: values });

    localStorage.setItem("checkbox", JSON.stringify([...new Set(addData)]));
  };

  checkBoxSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.value);
  };
  render() {
    const arr = ["Branch 1", "Branch 2", "Branch 3"];
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.checkBoxSubmit}>
          <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
            <List className="courses-college-regis">
              {arr.map((a, key) => (
                <ListItem button key={key}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    label={a}
                    value={a}
                    type="checkbox"
                    name={a}
                    checked={this.state.checked.includes(a)}
                    control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                    onClick={e => this.CheckedBox(e, a)}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </FormGroup>
          Count :{this.state.count}
          <br />
          <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default BranchComponent;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer nasir....but....if used these code...unable to store values in the local storage

Comment: So you want to store only selected check box value ?

Comment: and also store data in local storage

Comment: Please share example json i will help you

Comment: thanks very nasir bro...fro your help...i got one problem in these....if tried to select two check boxes....i am unable to do that

Comment: Hi brother okay give me a some time  i will post my anser here

Comment: Hi i updated my code is working according your requirements :-)

Comment: i have asked one quetion in stackover flow..can you please see and answer

Comment: can you share a link your question with me :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832761/how-to-post-check-box-value-and-checked-status/61833019#61833019