# Replacing array with filter on multiple not conditions returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Details**:
I have an array of objects tied to the UI. When clicking on an item it triggers the ***toggleFilter*** method. If the item wasn't selected, it gets pushed into the filters array (which works fine). However, when I deselect an item it removes all of the entries that partially match the filter conditions.

Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

**Data**:

```
filters:[
    {"column":"name","value":"Test 1"},
    {"column":"name","value":"Test 2"},
    {"column":"name","value":"Test 3"},
    {"column":"shortName","value":"XXX"}
]
```

**Method**:

```
toggleFilter(item) {
    item.active = !item.active

    if(item.active) {
        this.filters.push({ column: item.column, value: item.value })
    }
    else {
        this.filters = this.filters.filter(f => (f.column !== item.column && f.value !== item.value))
    }
}
```

For example, if I select 4 filters, and then go to deselect the one where the object ***value*** is ***Test 3***, all of the ones where the ***column*** is ***name*** also get removed.

**Output:**

```
filters:[
    {"column":"shortName","value":"XXX"}
]
```

**Expected:**

```
filters:[
    {"column":"name","value":"Test 1"},
    {"column":"name","value":"Test 2"},
    {"column":"shortName","value":"XXX"}
]
```

I need to filter on two conditions, as sometimes the column may differ, but the value may be the same, and I only want to remove the one that is deselected and replace the filters array. ie:

```
filters:[
    {"column":"name","value":"test1"},
    {"column":"shortName","value":"test1"}
]
```

Comment: you should use uniq identifier in data like id etc, its easy to track and remove and other things you can mange this by index

Comment: The best way to determine what is happening in code is to step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: But I think you want OR, not AND, between your two criteria in your filter.

Comment: try this ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61729934/11776310

Comment: Thanks, I was so hung up on thinking it needed an AND that I didn't even bother trying the OR, which works.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you add an answer saying change the AND to an OR so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR: Change `&&` to `||` in your filter expression.

Whenever I run into problems like this, I like to slow down and run the matches individually to make sure I understand how my logic is applying:

| `item` | `f` | `f.column !== item.column` | `f.value !== item.value` | `&&` | `||` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 3"}` | `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 1"}` | false | true | false | true |
| `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 3"}` | `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 2"}` | false | true | false | true |
| `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 3"}` | `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 3"}` | false | false | false | false |
| `{"column":"name", "value":"Test 3"}` | `{"column":"shortName", "value":"XXX"}` | true | true | true | true |

Hopefully you see the pattern, and why AND wasn't working, but OR does.